# Why is odds ratio used when interpreting logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, odds-ratio

I am fairly certain when interpreting logistic regression output, the odds ratio should be used instead of the estimated coefficients; however, I am unable to figure out ***why*** this is the case.

So my question is, can someone explain why the odds ratio is used instead of the estimated coefficients when interpreting logistic regression output?

Answer (score 6):

The problem with using the estimated coefficients for interpretation is that because of the link function used in Logistic regression their effect is nonlinear to $\bf{X}$.

\begin{equation}
log(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}) = \alpha + \beta X_i + \epsilon_i
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i} = exp(\alpha + \beta X_i) = e^\alpha e^{\beta X_i}
\end{equation}
Therefore, say if $\beta = 2$, increasing X by 1 unit, increases the odds by a *factor* of $e^2 \approx 7.4$.

This makes it easier to interpret odds ratios rather than the values of the coefficients.